# I have two df which i want the values which are not present in df2 when compared

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i have 2 dataframe like below

df1 :

| col 1 | col 2 |
| --- | --- |
| val1 | val2 |
| xyz | abc |
| ooo | ppp |

df2:

| col 1 | col 2 |
| --- | --- |
| val1 | mmmm |
| xyz | abc |
| ooo | sssss |

so here the first column is the same but 2nd is different. But i want to compare both the columns at a time get the difference based on their combination.

output:

| col 1 | col 2 |
| --- | --- |
| val1 | mmmm |
| ooo | sssss |

Comment: Your problem is absolutly not clear to me. Could you please give both dataframes in a copyable way and specify the problem as well as your aproach so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, and based on your expected output, you are looking to return all rows of `df2` where `df1['col 2']` does not match `df1['col 2']`. If so, you can simply use:

```
df2[df2['col 2'] != df1['col 2']]

  col 1  col 2
0  val1   mmmm
2   ooo  sssss
```

If you want `col 2` from both dfs here, you could do:

```
df1[df1['col 2'] != df2['col 2']].merge(df2, on='col 1', how='left', suffixes=['_df1','_df2'])

  col 1 col 2_df1 col 2_df2
0  val1      val2      mmmm
1   ooo       ppp     sssss
```

Or if you want to preserve the index:

```
df1[df1['col 2'] != df2['col 2']].reset_index().merge(df2, on='col 1', how='left', suffixes=['_df1','_df2']).set_index('index')

      col 1 col 2_df1 col 2_df2
index                          
0      val1      val2      mmmm
2       ooo       ppp     sssss
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try merge then filter

```py
out = (pd.merge(df1, df2, on='col 1', how='outer')
       .query('`col 2_x` != `col 2_y`'))
```

```
print(out)

  col 1 col 2_x col 2_y
0  val1    val2    mmmm
2   ooo     ppp   sssss
```